# Js files under clientlibs are not getting loaded

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, aem

The js files under clientlibs are not getting loaded , when I try to access those 
`clientlibs.js` using the url `//localhost:5555/etc/designs/MyProject/clientlibs.js` (I removed http here in this url because then it would be treated as link),
I'm getting a 404 error.

However, if I disable the minify option which is present in the HTML configuration in the felix console, then those js files are getting loaded. Actually the minify option is for compressing the CSS and JS files and also for removing white space characters. I'm not sure why my JS files are not getting loaded when that option is enabled. But in production we are supposed to enable that option.

May I know how we can load those JS files.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked where are the minified scripts placed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michal, Im not sure where the minified files are placed, what Im think is like if there is any syntax error in the js file , which is caught by the minifier because of which js files are not getting loaded. I will let you know when I come to know where those minified files are placed, thanks Michal

Comment: Hi Michal, actually there is one error in the js file  which is caught by the minifier, I found that error while trying to compressing the js file using the YUI compressor available online.Now I included the js file directly instead of using clientlibs so that I dont have any problems with minifier now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, enabling minify option is nothing but compressing the js files.When this option is enabled,and  if your js files are not found suddently(getting 404 error while trying to access these js files), then for sure these js files are throwing some error after compression. To confirm that, copy and paste each of  your js file content in the **YUI compressor** which is available online, and try to compress it using that compressor, if it throws error, it is a proof there is some error in the js file and you need to fix it.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe's documentation warns to delete the contents of clientlibs after making the config change:
    When changing the setting for either Minify or Gzip you will 
    also need to delete the contents of /var/clientlibs. 
    This is a cached version of the clientlibs and will be rebuilt 
    when next requested.

See doc here: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html

Answer (score 1):

Your JS minifier is probably placing minified files to different location.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into cq logs (error.log). It might be something wrong with one of js library which was included into the final clientlibs.js